# Connecting two computers via SNMP4J

Tags: java, virtualbox, snmp4j

I recently started to learn about snmp. I studied what it is and some open source codes to have a basic idea about how it works. Yet, I am still a beginner. My question is that is it possible to have a connection between two computers (Windows 8 as host and Ubuntu 14.04.01 LTS as guest on Virtualbox) using snmp4j? I tried to find a guide for similar action but i couldn't find. If anyone can show me a guide I would be happy.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**// Edited my answer to be more SNMP4J focused.**

Yes.

Install a agent on one machine and interrogate it from the other.

Quoting [SNMP4J](http://www.snmp4j.org/html/download.html) The SNMP4J Command Line Tool (CLT) can be used to send SNMPv1/v2c/v3 requests and traps to a target using UDP or TCP transport using IPv4 and IPv6 (if available on the used platform).  SNMP4J also have a SNMP4J-Agent sources and binaries are freely available at same page.

In parallel perhaps also install [NetSNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) and install its agent on one machine, and interrogate  it from the other machine, using snmp-walk etc commands.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, if my aim is not possible with SNMP4J I will try with NETSNMP. Do you know whether it is or not ?

Comment: As far as I know using UDP and IPv4 is easier, so I will use these info. If I'm not wrong IPv4 is unique, is UDP unique ? If so, where can I learn it from? I think I can set it while I am writing the agent for device, is it true?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565975/why-is-snmp-usually-run-over-udp-and-not-tcp-ip